# Getting 0x8000ffff Unhandled exception when I am assigning a Grid to Scroll Viewer in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am creating a grid dynamically through code behind file and assigning that dynamically generated grid to the scroll viewer which is present in **xaml file** i am using statement like

```
scroll_viewer.Content=grid
```

which gives me Unhandled `Exception 0x8000ffff`.
Can anyone help me in this why i am getting this

Comment: Post the code that created the grid dynamically. Also post .xaml for the scroll viewer

Comment: Post more code, including XAML and entire code from `Grid` creation until the assignment.